# Please check my proof of 'Show that the third axiom cannot be deduced from the other two.'

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms

I have been trying to answer the question "Show that the third axiom cannot be deduced from the other two.", where the first axiom is $p \Rightarrow(q \Rightarrow p)$ , the second axiom is $(p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)) \Rightarrow ((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow r))$ and the third axiom is $((p \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow p$.

I think I have come up with a proof, but I'm unsure as to it's validity, so please tell me what you think. If it is incorrect, please do not tell me a valid proof as I still would like to figure this out for myself.

**Proof:**

If the 3rd axiom can be deduced from the first two axioms, then it can be deduced from a system whose only rules of inference are the deduction theorem and modus ponens, as the first 2 axioms can be trivially deduced from these rules. However,
$$\{(p \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot\}\vdash p $$
is the only logical statement that is equivalent (by the Deduction Theorem) to
$$\vdash((p \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow p$$.

As modus ponens requires at least 2 initial propositions to infer new propositions, neither of these situations allow for further deductions, so there is no way to construct a proof from these 2 inference rules, and thus the 3rd axiom cannot be deduced from the first two.

Comment: If your logical system is *complete* you can use the method of interpretations to show that the last axiom cannot be deduced from the first two. Just find a truth assignment for propositional constants which makes the first two axioms true and the last one false.

Comment: "If the 3rd axiom can be deduced from the first two axioms, then it can be deduced from a system whose only rules of inference are the deduction theorem and modus ponens..."  This isn't correct.  You also need a rule that allows you to introduce new assumptions.

Comment: @anfauglit I had considered that approach, but the 3rd axiom is a tautology so any truth assignment will make it a true statement, I think.

Comment: To prove independence of the third axiom you can note the following: If a formula $A$ is deducible from the first two axioms, then $A[p/\bot]$ is deducible, where $A[p/\bot]$ denotes the formula obtained by changing every occurrence of $\bot$ in $A$ by (any fixed) $p$. You can see this easily by induction on the length of the proof for $A$. So if you can deduce $((p\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow p$, then you can also deduce $((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q)\rightarrow p$, but this is not a tautology.